# How to do a multiplication based on a ForeignKey in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, foreign-keys

Hello guys i have this 2 models in django, and has you can see im overriding the `save()` method because i want the atribute `valor_a_receber` to be based on a basic multiplication with a foreignkey value
Here is my source code:

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Vendedor


class Comissao(models.Model):
    porcentagem = models.FloatField()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.porcentagem)


class Venda(models.Model):
    vendedor = models.ForeignKey(Vendedor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    comissao_venda = models.ForeignKey(Comissao, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data_venda = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    valor_venda = models.FloatField()
    descricao_venda = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    valor_a_receber = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.valor_a_receber = (self.comissao_venda * self.valor_venda)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vendedor)
```

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: `self.comissao_venda.porcentagem * self.valor_venda`?

Comment: ok...i am SOOOO dumb..

Comment: how can i put your answer as the right one, BTW im aprecciate your help...XD

Comment: Just mark Willem's answer as correct he points out a better alternative anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should multiply with the `porcentagem` of the `comissao_vendra`:

```
self.valor_a_receber = self.comissao_venda.porcentagem * self.valor_venda
```

but it is probably *not* a good idea to implement this in the `save` method. These can be circumvented, for example when performing an [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) on a `QuerySet`. It might be better to define `valor_a_receber` as a *property* instead:

```
class Venda(models.Model):
    vendedor = models.ForeignKey(Vendedor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    comissao_venda = models.ForeignKey(Comissao, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data_venda = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    valor_venda = models.FloatField()
    descricao_venda = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    # ↓ not a field
    @property
    def valor_a_receber(self):
        return self.comissao_venda.porcentagem * self.valor_venda

    # no override of save
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your help, i firstly tought about using the property way, but then i came across someone saying to override the save() method so i did it, but once again aprecciate your help, and i just learned something new AMAZING

Comment: going to put your answer as the right one, since the other guy only commented